# What makes the output difference?

Tags: python

```
def f1(p):
    p.extend([4])
def f2(p):
    p += [4]
def f3(p):
    p = p+ [4]

a = [1,2,3]
f1(a)
print(a)

a = [1,2,3]
f2(a)
print(a)

a = [1,2,3]
f3(a)
print(a)
```

In the function f2 and f3 the outputs are different
why is that? It seems like the same equation.

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Namespaces. In `f3` you are changing `p` in the local namespace of the function only.

Comment: That's why it's usually safe to return a value from a function and assign it to some variable while calling the function. In this case, try adding `return p` in each function and see for yourself what happens. You will see `each function call will return [1,2,3,4] but a will not be mutated in the last one, i.e., in f3` . To correct that you can overwrite `a` or assign to some other variable such as `b` and print them using `a = f3(a); print(a)` or `b = f3(a); print (b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f1` an `f2` mutate the list object `a`. The operation in `f3` creates a new list, but does not mutate `a`.

You would have to return `p` from `f3` and assign that return value to the variable `a` if you want the same result